# Using UNNotificationServiceExtension for rich remote notifications

Tags: ios, ios10, rich-notifications

I am trying to implement the rich remote notifications in ios 10. I have implemented this code. The control after receiving the notification is going here, but I don't know how to download the image and display in the notifications. Thanks in advance.

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

var contentHandler: ((UNNotificationContent) -> Void)?
var bestAttemptContent: UNMutableNotificationContent?

override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        // Modify the notification content here...
        //print("title for image = \(bestAttemptContent.title)")
        bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"

        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }

}



override func serviceExtensionTimeWillExpire() {
    // Called just before the extension will be terminated by the system.
    // Use this as an opportunity to deliver your "best attempt" at modified content, otherwise the original push payload will be used.
    if let contentHandler = contentHandler, let bestAttemptContent =  bestAttemptContent {
        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will get an attachment in your `notificationData` like this

```
"attachment-url": "https://yourimage.png"
```

and this is how you can use it

```
self.contentHandler = contentHandler
        bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        // Get the custom data from the notification payload
        if let notificationData = request.content.userInfo["data"] as? [String: String] {
            // Grab the attachment
            if let urlString = notificationData["attachment-url"], let fileUrl = URL(string: urlString) {
                // Download the attachment
                URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: fileUrl) { (location, response, error) in
                    if let location = location {
                        // Move temporary file to remove .tmp extension
                        let tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
                        let tmpFile = "file://".appending(tmpDirectory).appending(fileUrl.lastPathComponent)
                        let tmpUrl = URL(string: tmpFile)!
                        try! FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: tmpUrl)

                        // Add the attachment to the notification content
                        if let attachment = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "", url: tmpUrl) {
                            self.bestAttemptContent?.attachments = [attachment]
                        }
                    }
                    // Serve the notification content
                    self.contentHandler!(self.bestAttemptContent!)
                    }.resume()
            }
        }
```

Referenced from [here](https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-send-ios-10-notifications-using-the-push-notifications-api/)

Comment: thanks for your reply @Rajat . I tried this, but it is still not downloading the image. Still displaying just the text data. I don't know what is that I'm doing wrong

Comment: Check whether file is downloading or not, also check you are getting valid url from Notification data

Comment: yes the url is valid. But at what location are they going to be stored?? I went through photos , there was none.

Comment: You are saving your image in `NSTemporaryDirectory ` temp directory not on Photos

Comment: yes but which folder should I search for the image. I am sorry if I sound silly.

Comment: You need to download you app's sandbox folder, from there check in the Temp Directory for your image

Comment: Do I have to pass something to the identifier in UNNotificationAttachment Consructor??

Comment: Can you check this link [Works only in dev cert not on prod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42672502/richmedia-notification-notification-not-working-in-production-certifcate-norm)

Answer (score 0):

Finally its working. The issue here was that I had to add

> NSAppTransportSecurity

tag in plist of the extension. After adding this tag, it started displaying the images. Hope it helps someone.